# How to count the number of repeated elements in Dataframe and give it a count number

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'Sample':['S1', 'S1', 'S1' ,'S1' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S3', 'S4', 'Negative', 'Positive', 'Negative',
                     'S1', 'S1', 'S1' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S4', 'S4', 'Positive', 'Positive', 'Negative'], 
           'Location':['A1', 'A2', 'A3' ,'A4' ,'A5' ,'A6' ,'A7' ,'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12',
                       'B1', 'B2', 'B3' ,'B4' ,'B5' ,'B6' ,'B7' ,'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11', 'B12']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

For the example code above, I want to count the repeated items in column 'Sample' of same location group and give it a repeat number in a new column 'Repeat Number'. For example, there are 4 S1 in location group A, I want to give the first S1 repeat number 1 and the second S1 repeat number 2 and so on.
For location B, there are 3 S1, give the first S1 repeat number 1 and the second S1 repeat number 2 and so on.

Ideal result would look like this:

```
data = {'Sample':['S1', 'S1', 'S1' ,'S1' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S3', 'S4', 'Negative', 'Positive', 'Negative',
                      'S1', 'S1', 'S1' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S4', 'S4', 'Positive', 'Positive', 'Negative'], 
            'Location':['A1', 'A2', 'A3' ,'A4' ,'A5' ,'A6' ,'A7' ,'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12',
                        'B1', 'B2', 'B3' ,'B4' ,'B5' ,'B6' ,'B7' ,'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11', 'B12'],
       'Repeat Number':['1', '2', '3' ,'4' ,'1' ,'2' ,'1' ,'2', '1', '1', '1', '2',
                      '1', '2', '3' ,'1' ,'2' ,'3' ,'1' ,'1', '2', '1', '2', '1',]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ansev's (original) answer will work only if the `Sample` column is already sorted in relation to the `Location` column because it compares `Sample` to `Sample.shift()`.

If that is not the case, you should either use `sort_values` first, or group by both the `Sample` column and the result of `df1['Location'].str.extract('(^[A-Z])')`:

```
df1['Repeat Number'] = df1.groupby(['Sample', df1['Location'].str.extract('(^[A-Z])')[0]]).cumcount() + 1
print(df1)

      Sample Location  Repeat Number
0         S1       A1              1
1         S1       A2              2
2         S1       A3              3
3         S1       A4              4
4         S2       A5              1
5         S2       A6              2
6         S3       A7              1
7         S3       A8              2
8         S4       A9              1
9   Negative      A10              1
10  Positive      A11              1
11  Negative      A12              2
12        S1       B1              1
13        S1       B2              2
14        S1       B3              3
15        S2       B4              1
16        S2       B5              2
17        S2       B6              3
18        S3       B7              1
19        S4       B8              1
20        S4       B9              2
21  Positive      B10              1
22  Positive      B11              2
23  Negative      B12              1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

```
blocks = df1['Sample'].ne(df1['Sample'].shift()).cumsum()
df1['Repeat Number'] = df1.groupby(blocks).cumcount().add(1)
# if you want str type
#df1['Repeat Number'] = df1.groupby(blocks).cumcount().add(1).asype(str)
```

blocks is incremented from the previous row each time `Sample` changes

```
print(blocks)

0      1
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      2
5      2
6      3
7      3
8      4
9      5
10     6
11     7
12     8
13     8
14     8
15     9
16     9
17     9
18    10
19    11
20    11
21    12
22    12
23    13
Name: Sample, dtype: int64
```

Another option is:

```
location_blocks = df1['Location'].str[0]
df1['Repeat Number'] = df1.groupby([location_blocks, 'Sample']).cumcount().add(1)
```

**Output**

```
print(df1)

      Sample Location  Repeat Number
0         S1       A1              1
1         S1       A2              2
2         S1       A3              3
3         S1       A4              4
4         S2       A5              1
5         S2       A6              2
6         S3       A7              1
7         S3       A8              2
8         S4       A9              1
9   Negative      A10              1
10  Positive      A11              1
11  Negative      A12              1
12        S1       B1              1
13        S1       B2              2
14        S1       B3              3
15        S2       B4              1
16        S2       B5              2
17        S2       B6              3
18        S3       B7              1
19        S4       B8              1
20        S4       B9              2
21  Positive      B10              1
22  Positive      B11              2
23  Negative      B12              1
```

---

Comment: I suspect this will not work if the `Sample` column is not already sorted in relation to the `Location` column because this naively compares `Sample` to `Sample.shift()`, am I correct? In this case you might have to resort to grouping by `df1['Location'].str.extract('(^[A-Z])')`

Answer (score 0):

**Working code is here, maintain a dictionary and update the count;
works for one character groups only (i.e. A, B, a, b - Z, z etc.)**

> **Code**

```
dictionary={}

def countdict(s, l):
    l=l[0]
    if dictionary.get(s+l, 0):
        dictionary[s+l]=dictionary[s+l]+1
        return dictionary[s+l]
    else:
        dictionary[s+l]=1
        return 1

data = {'Sample':['S1', 'S1', 'S1' ,'S1' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S3', 'S4', 'Negative', 'Positive', 'Negative',
                     'S1', 'S1', 'S1' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S4', 'S4', 'Positive', 'Positive', 'Negative'], 
           'Location':['A1', 'A2', 'A3' ,'A4' ,'A5' ,'A6' ,'A7' ,'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12',
                       'B1', 'B2', 'B3' ,'B4' ,'B5' ,'B6' ,'B7' ,'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11', 'B12']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1['Repeat Number']=df1.apply(lambda vals: countdict(*vals), axis=1)
df1
```

> **Output**

```
      Sample Location  Repeat Number
0         S1       A1              1
1         S1       A2              2
2         S1       A3              3
3         S1       A4              4
4         S2       A5              1
5         S2       A6              2
6         S3       A7              1
7         S3       A8              2
8         S4       A9              1
9   Negative      A10              1
10  Positive      A11              1
11  Negative      A12              2
12        S1       B1              1
13        S1       B2              2
14        S1       B3              3
15        S2       B4              1
16        S2       B5              2
17        S2       B6              3
18        S3       B7              1
19        S4       B8              1
20        S4       B9              2
21  Positive      B10              1
22  Positive      B11              2
23  Negative      B12              1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses `.factorize()` and `.groupby().rank()`.  I created temporary columns to simplify the `groupby()` statement.

```
# pull 'A' or 'B' out of the Location column
df1['location_group'] = df1['Location'].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+)')

# convert Sample to integer
df1['x'] = df1['Sample'].factorize()[0]

# use .rank(method='first') so that every entry has a unique number
df1['Repeat Number'] = (
    df1.groupby(['location_group', 'Sample'])['x'].rank(method='first')
    .astype(int))

# clean up
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['location_group', 'x'])

# show results
print(df1)


      Sample Location  Repeat Number
0         S1       A1              1
1         S1       A2              2
2         S1       A3              3
3         S1       A4              4
4         S2       A5              1
5         S2       A6              2
6         S3       A7              1
7         S3       A8              2
8         S4       A9              1
9   Negative      A10              1
10  Positive      A11              1
11  Negative      A12              2
12        S1       B1              1
13        S1       B2              2
14        S1       B3              3
15        S2       B4              1
16        S2       B5              2
17        S2       B6              3
18        S3       B7              1
19        S4       B8              1
20        S4       B9              2
21  Positive      B10              1
22  Positive      B11              2
23  Negative      B12              1
```

Then, I called the expected result `df2` and verified with:

```
assert (df1 == df2).all
```